# After I made paragraph style for my body text a lot of words are with bad letter spacing

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

[image]

Hello, 
After I created a paragraph style for my body text and I applied it to the whole text now I have very bad letter spacing with a lot of words. I already used find/change and I replaced all doublespacing with singled, because I tough that might be the problem, but it didn't help.

P.S. I am sorry that the text is in different language, I hope that this is not a problem.

Comment: It's "force" justified. Set to simply "justified".

Answer (score 2):

Try changing from "Justify all lines" to "Justify with line aligned left".

[image]